# Batch: simple game syntax is wrong, can't figure out why?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The game code is pretty simple, the code for it is below. Can't figure out why syntax for `:WRONG` section is well wrong. I've tried mirroring it exactly from the start section which works and is identical. Anyone offer any input?

```
color 4a
cls
:MAIN
@echo off
echo Welcome to XXXX's Trivia Game!!
pause & echo Ready to start?
set /p input=(Y/N)
if %input%==y goto SECTION1
goto BYE
:BYE
@echo Sorry to see you leave! Have a nice day!
pause
exit
:SECTION1
@echo FIRST QUESTION!!!!
pause 
cls & echo At what temperature does rain turn to snow?
echo A. 112 degrees
echo B. -37 degrees
echo C. 32 degrees
echo D. 17,341 degrees
set /p input=Answer?
if %input%==C goto 2
goto WRONG
:SECTION2
:SECTION3
:SECTION4
:SECTION5
:SECTION6
:SECTION7
:SECTION8
:SECTION9
:SECTION10
:WRONG
cls & echo You were wrong, would you like to start again?
set /p input==(Y/N)
if %input%==y goto :SECTION1
goto BYE
pause
:HALFWAY
:WIN
```

Things I've tried:

- Removing all sections between `:SECTION1` and `:WRONG`
- Renaming `:WRONG` and the call for it in `:SECTION1`
- Removing `:HALFWAY` and `:WIN`
- Copying from `:MAIN` (working correctly) to `:WRONG` (still no dice)

Comment: Didn't dig deep in, I suggest you add the /i switch to your if, so the compare is case independent. You ask for uppercase answer and compare lowercase y. If you just hit enter the var input is undefined and will return an error because this resolves to `if ==y` which is incorrect syntax.

Comment: You're amazing, thanks. Didn't even know the /i switch existed! Thank you tons. Will definitely explore more.

Comment: Remove the second `=` sign in `set /p input==(Y/N)`...

Comment: **1.** `set /p input==(Y/N)` should be `set /p input=(Y/N)`; **2.** use `if /I "%input%"=="y" goto SECTION1`; **3.** read `choice /?` it could be a simple alternative to `set /P`.

Comment: Thank you all! This choice command is great, looking into that more.

Answer (score 0):

The following command has an extra `=` that causes a syntax error:

```
set /p input==(Y/N)
```

The prompt for `set /p` cannot begin with `=`. Remove the unwanted char as follows, and the command will work.

```
set /p input=(Y/N)
```

You are reusing the `input` variable, and `set /p` will preserve any pre-existing value if the user simply presses `<Enter>`. You should clear the value before prompting for input.

```
set "input="
set /p input=(Y/N)
```

There are lots of additional areas where your code could (should) be improved, but I will let you discover them at your own pace.

Comment: Great, didn't realize I could clear pre-existing values, will keep that in mind so I don't have to come up with tons of variables. Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

A basic yes/no choice command example for you:

```bat
@Choice /M "Ready to start?"
@Echo=%%ERRORLEVEL%% is %ERRORLEVEL%
@Timeout 5
```

*Run it and see what happens when you enter different options.*

Comment: Yeah, I've been messing with Choice now for the better part of an hour. Much cleaner for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your game :)

Try the below code...

Edit: Did some code improvements and cleanup, hope you'd like it...

```
@echo off
color 4a
cls

:MAIN
cls
echo.
echo --------------------------------------
echo Welcome to New-B-Admin's Trivia Game!!
echo --------------------------------------
echo.
set /p input="Ready to start playing ? Answer (Y/N): "

if /i "%input%"=="y" goto SECTION1
if /i "%input%"=="n" goto BYE
if not "%input%"=="Place_Holder_Value_Dont_Remove" goto MAIN


:SECTION1
cls
echo ------------------
echo Question Number 1
echo ------------------
echo. 
echo At what temperature does rain turn to snow?
echo.
echo A. 112 degrees
echo B. -37 degrees
echo C. 32 degrees
echo D. 17,341 degrees
echo.

set /p input="Your answer?: "

if /i "%input%"=="a" goto WRONG

if /i "%input%"=="b" goto WRONG

if /i "%input%"=="c" (
    call :CORRECT
    goto SECTION2
)
if /i "%input%"=="d" goto WRONG

::the below if statment prevents the user from just hitting Enter Key or any non relevant letters or numbers.

if not "%input%"=="Place_Holder_Value_Dont_Remove" goto SECTION1 rem rename this goto statment to the same name as the label.    

:SECTION2
cls
echo ------------------
echo Question Number 2
echo ------------------
echo. 
echo What year was the two dollar bill last printed in the United States?
echo.
echo A. 1997
echo B. 2001
echo C. 2003
echo D. 2007
echo.

set /p input="Your answer?: "

if /i "%input%"=="a" goto WRONG

if /i "%input%"=="b" goto WRONG

if /i "%input%"=="c" (
    call :CORRECT
    goto SECTION3
)

if /i "%input%"=="d" goto WRONG

:: the below if statment prevents the user from just hitting Enter Key or any non relevant letters or numbers.

if not "%input%"=="Place_Holder_Value_Dont_Remove" goto SECTION2 rem rename this goto statment to the same name as the label.

:SECTION3
cls
echo ------------------
echo Question Number 3
echo ------------------
echo. 
echo How many super bowls have the Denver Broncos won?
echo.
echo A. 5
echo B. 10
echo C. 7
echo D. 3
echo.

set /p input="Your answer?: "

if /i "%input%"=="a" goto WRONG

if /i "%input%"=="b" goto WRONG

if /i "%input%"=="d" (
    call :CORRECT
    goto SECTION4
)

if /i "%input%"=="c" goto WRONG

:: the below if statment prevents the user from just hitting Enter Key or any non relevant letters or numbers.

if not "%input%"=="Place_Holder_Value_Dont_Remove" goto SECTION3 rem rename this goto statment to the same name as the label.

:SECTION4
cls
echo ------------------
echo Question Number 4
echo ------------------
echo. 
echo What was the name of the hourse from The Lone Ranger Movie that he saved from an enraged buffalo?
echo.
echo A. Silver
echo B. Yellow
echo C. White
echo D. Buck
echo.

set /p input="Your answer?: "

if /i "%input%"=="c" goto WRONG

if /i "%input%"=="b" goto WRONG

if /i "%input%"=="a" (
    call :CORRECT
    goto SECTION5
)

if /i "%input%"=="d" goto WRONG

:: the below if statment prevents the user from just hitting Enter Key or any non relevant letters or numbers.

if not "%input%"=="Place_Holder_Value_Dont_Remove" goto SECTION4 rem rename this goto statment to the same name as the label.

:SECTION5
:SECTION6
:SECTION7
:SECTION8
:SECTION9
:SECTION10


:END
cls
echo.
echo --------------------
echo No more questions!!!
echo --------------------
echo.
set /p input="Would you like to restart the game ? Answer (Y/N): "
if /i "%input%"=="y" goto SECTION1
if /i "%input%"=="n" goto BYE
if not "%input%"=="Place_Holder_Value_Dont_Remove" goto END

:WRONG
cls
echo.
set /p input="You were wrong, would you like to start again?(Y/N): "
if /i "%input%"=="y" goto SECTION1
if /i "%input%"=="n" goto BYE
if not "%input%"=="Place_Holder_Value_Dont_Remove" goto WRONG

:CORRECT
cls
set input=0
echo.
echo Correct!!! Great progress :)
echo Press enter to continue to next question...
pause >nul
goto :EOF

:HALFWAY

:WIN

:BYE
cls
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------
echo Sorry to see you leave! Have a nice day!
echo ----------------------------------------
pause >nul
exit
```

Comment: Haha, didn't even think of incorporating a correct screen. let alone calling a separate part of the batch script. That's pretty awesome.